# While loop ending with a switch: should I use "break" or "continue" to conclude cases?

Tags: c#, while-loop, switch-statement, break, continue

Curiosity question, and pretty simple.

Assuming I have a `while` loop, and the last piece of code executed inside this loop is a `switch` statement, should I finish my `case` blocks with `break`, or with `continue`?

The result of the execution is virtually the same as far as I can tell. Is one of them faster? Are there weird edge cases?

```
while (ShouldLoop)
{
     switch (myInt)
     {
         case 0:
             doStuff();
             break; // or continue?
         default:
             break; // that is the question.
     }
 }
```

Comment: It depends on your logic, `break` breaks the entire loop and continue execution of code after loop, `continue` will process the next iteration of the loop

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski As the `break` is inside a `switch`, it will break out of the switch and not the loop.

Comment: Use `break` otherwise it's confusing to read because you have to mentally switch context from the `switch` to the `while`.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly you should be finishing your case statement blocks with `break`.  Consider the two scenarios:

- If all that's important is you don't fall through to the below `case` statements then you should use `break`.
- You've provided an incomplete code sample and there could be code following the `switch` statement which you want to skip on certain cases.  In this scenario a `continue` statement would be more appropriate than the above scenario, but this is already sounding a bit like spaghetti.  If this were the case you'd probably be better setting a boolean variable in your `case` statement block and using a `break`.  Then you could wrap the following code with an `if` statement on this boolean flag.

It's a bit subjective because both 'work', but one has much clearer intent IMO.

Answer (score 2):

`continue` will always act on the enclosing `while` loop, no matter where you place it in your code, instructing the compiler to continue with the next evaluation of the `ShouldLoop` while stopping execution of any code after the continuation. On the other hand, `break` acts differently whether you place it at the 1st level of your `while` loop where it would simply exit the loop, whereas placing it inside of `switch-case` would stop evaluation and exit the `switch-case` once the compiler encounters the keyword.

As @simon-pearson pointed out, there might be cases where `continue` inside `switch-case` would make sense, but that definitely is not a readable code and such use-cases should be replaced by some other workaround.
Usually, `switch-case` should be written with `break`.